# Is there a way to pattern match infix operations with precedence in Rust macros?

Tags: macros, rust

A very simple example would be to implement basic addition and multiplication in Rust macros.

```
compute!(1 + 2 * 3) // should evaluate to 7
```

I'm not completely sure it's possible due to Rust macro's limited grammar.

The point here is not to compute something at compile-time, but to be able to somehow parse the tokens (with precedence):

```
(term, terms*) => { parse_mul!(term) + (parse_mul!(terms))* } // this is not actual Rust!
```

Comment: It's not about doing maths in macros, it's about having precedence in macros.

Comment: I've updated the question. The idea here is to be able to parse the operations. It doesn't matter if you simply reimplement default Rust arithmetic.

Comment: I think you can implement it like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=90d5bd39a561adcd2e0a609757daca6e

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In theory, you can do it. In practice, it's a bad idea. I did it anyway. I posted this on reddit and was requested to transfer it here.

Such a macro would necessarily be a "tt muncher", a macro which recurses to itself to parse one token of its input at a time. This is required because as pointed out in the comments above, it's the only way to pull apart an expression like `a + b`. These so-called ["future-proofing restrictions"](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0550-macro-future-proofing.md) are in place for good reason, and tt munchers circumvent them. The recursion also means that the time to expand the macro is linear in the length of the expression, at least. And rustc will give up expanding macros after recursing 64 times, by default (but you can change the limit on stable).

With those caveats in mind, let's see the macro! The strategy I have chosen is to transform the infix expression into postfix, and then evaluate the postfix expression, which is fairly simple to do. I very vaguely remember how to do this but since the objective here is macro craziness, not algorithmic tricks, I just followed the rules at the bottom of [this helpful page](http://csis.pace.edu/~wolf/CS122/infix-postfix.htm).

Without further ado, the code ([runnable version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=971606d4b311a2841ed9565c26f462c4&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
macro_rules! infix {
    // done converting
    (@cvt () $postfix:tt) => { infix!(@pfx () $postfix) };
    //                                |    |  ^ postfix expression
    //                                |    ^ operand stack
    //                                ^ postfix interpreter

    // infix to postfix conversion using the rules at the bottom of this page: http://csis.pace.edu/~wolf/CS122/infix-postfix.htm

    // at end of input, flush the operators to postfix
    (@cvt ($ophead:tt $($optail:tt)*) ($($postfix:tt)*)) => { infix!(@cvt ($($optail)*) ($($postfix)* $ophead)) };

    // 2. push an operator onto the stack if it's empty or has a left-paren on top
    (@cvt (                 ) $postfix:tt + $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt (+               ) $postfix $($tail)*) };
    (@cvt (                 ) $postfix:tt - $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt (-               ) $postfix $($tail)*) };
    (@cvt (                 ) $postfix:tt * $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt (*               ) $postfix $($tail)*) };
    (@cvt (                 ) $postfix:tt / $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt (/               ) $postfix $($tail)*) };
    (@cvt (LP $($optail:tt)*) $postfix:tt + $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt (+ LP $($optail)*) $postfix $($tail)*) };
    (@cvt (LP $($optail:tt)*) $postfix:tt - $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt (- LP $($optail)*) $postfix $($tail)*) };
    (@cvt (LP $($optail:tt)*) $postfix:tt * $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt (* LP $($optail)*) $postfix $($tail)*) };
    (@cvt (LP $($optail:tt)*) $postfix:tt / $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt (/ LP $($optail)*) $postfix $($tail)*) };

    // 3. push a left-paren onto the stack
    (@cvt ($($operator:tt)*) $postfix:tt ($($inner:tt)*) $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt (LP $($operator)*) $postfix $($inner)* RP $($tail)*) };

    // 4. see right-paren, pop operators to postfix until left-paren
    (@cvt (LP         $($optail:tt)*) $postfix:tt       RP $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt ($($optail)*) $postfix               $($tail)*   ) };
    (@cvt ($ophead:tt $($optail:tt)*) ($($postfix:tt)*) RP $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt ($($optail)*) ($($postfix)* $ophead) RP $($tail)*) };

    // 5. if an operator w/ lower precedence is on top, just push
    (@cvt (+ $($optail:tt)*) $postfix:tt * $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt (* + $($optail)*) $postfix $($tail)*) };
    (@cvt (- $($optail:tt)*) $postfix:tt * $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt (* - $($optail)*) $postfix $($tail)*) };
    (@cvt (+ $($optail:tt)*) $postfix:tt / $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt (/ + $($optail)*) $postfix $($tail)*) };
    (@cvt (- $($optail:tt)*) $postfix:tt / $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt (/ - $($optail)*) $postfix $($tail)*) };

    // 6. if an operator w/ equal precedence is on top, pop and push
    (@cvt (+ $($optail:tt)*) ($($postfix:tt)*) + $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt (+ $($optail)*) ($($postfix)* +) $($tail)*) };
    (@cvt (- $($optail:tt)*) ($($postfix:tt)*) - $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt (- $($optail)*) ($($postfix)* -) $($tail)*) };
    (@cvt (+ $($optail:tt)*) ($($postfix:tt)*) - $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt (- $($optail)*) ($($postfix)* +) $($tail)*) };
    (@cvt (- $($optail:tt)*) ($($postfix:tt)*) + $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt (+ $($optail)*) ($($postfix)* -) $($tail)*) };
    (@cvt (* $($optail:tt)*) ($($postfix:tt)*) * $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt (* $($optail)*) ($($postfix)* *) $($tail)*) };
    (@cvt (/ $($optail:tt)*) ($($postfix:tt)*) / $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt (/ $($optail)*) ($($postfix)* /) $($tail)*) };
    (@cvt (* $($optail:tt)*) ($($postfix:tt)*) / $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt (/ $($optail)*) ($($postfix)* *) $($tail)*) };
    (@cvt (/ $($optail:tt)*) ($($postfix:tt)*) * $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt (* $($optail)*) ($($postfix)* /) $($tail)*) };

    // 7. if an operator w/ higher precedence is on top, pop it to postfix
    (@cvt (* $($optail:tt)*) ($($postfix:tt)*) + $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt ($($optail)*) ($($postfix)* *) + $($tail)*) };
    (@cvt (* $($optail:tt)*) ($($postfix:tt)*) - $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt ($($optail)*) ($($postfix)* *) - $($tail)*) };
    (@cvt (/ $($optail:tt)*) ($($postfix:tt)*) + $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt ($($optail)*) ($($postfix)* /) + $($tail)*) };
    (@cvt (/ $($optail:tt)*) ($($postfix:tt)*) - $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt ($($optail)*) ($($postfix)* /) - $($tail)*) };

    // 1. operands go to the postfix output
    (@cvt $operators:tt ($($postfix:tt)*) $head:tt $($tail:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt $operators ($($postfix)* ($head)) $($tail)*) };

    // postfix interpreter
    (@pfx ($result:expr                     ) (                     )) => { $result };
    (@pfx (($a:expr) ($b:expr) $($stack:tt)*) (+        $($tail:tt)*)) => { infix!(@pfx ((($b + $a)) $($stack)*) ($($tail)*)) };
    (@pfx (($a:expr) ($b:expr) $($stack:tt)*) (-        $($tail:tt)*)) => { infix!(@pfx ((($b - $a)) $($stack)*) ($($tail)*)) };
    (@pfx (($a:expr) ($b:expr) $($stack:tt)*) (*        $($tail:tt)*)) => { infix!(@pfx ((($b * $a)) $($stack)*) ($($tail)*)) };
    (@pfx (($a:expr) ($b:expr) $($stack:tt)*) (/        $($tail:tt)*)) => { infix!(@pfx ((($b / $a)) $($stack)*) ($($tail)*)) };
    (@pfx ($($stack:tt)*                    ) ($head:tt $($tail:tt)*)) => { infix!(@pfx ($head       $($stack)*) ($($tail)*)) };

    ($($t:tt)*) => { infix!(@cvt () () $($t)*) }
    //                      |    |  |  ^ infix expression
    //                      |    |  ^ postfix expression
    //                      |    ^ operator stack
    //                      ^ convert infix to postfix
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", infix!(1 + 2 * 3));
    println!("{}", infix!(1 * 2 + 3));
    println!("{}", infix!(((1 + 2) * 3) * 3));
    println!("{}", infix!(( 1 + 2  * 3) * 3));
    println!("{}", infix!(1 - 2 - 1));
}
```

Most of the macro tricks I used here can be found in [The Little Book of Rust Macros](http://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/). You can see that the macro is divided into three sections: the infix-to-postfix conversion (all rules that start with `@cvt`), the postfix interpreter (all rules that start with `@pfx`), and the single entry point (the last rule, with no prefix).

The converter uses an operator stack and builds up the postfix output string as it chews through the input. Parentheses are converted to `LP` and `RP` to keep the input as a linear stream of tokens (normally `macro_rules` requires parentheses to stay balanced and matches a parenthesized group as a single token-tree). All operators are considered to be right-associative, and PEMDAS applies (`*` and `/` have precedence over `+` and `-`).

The interpreter uses an operand stack and evaluates the expression in a rather straightforward way: push operands onto the stack, and when encountering an operator pop off two operands and apply the operator. The result of the postfix interpreter is an expression quite similar to the original infix expression, but with everything parenthesized to simulate operator precedence. We then rely on rustc to do the actual arithmetic :)

A few examples are included at the end of the code. Let me know if you find any bugs! One limitation is that each operand must be a single token-tree, so input like `5.0f32.sqrt()` will cause a parse error and multi-token literals like `-2` might cause wrong answers. You can fix this with curly braces, e.g. `infix!({-2.0} - {5.0f32.sqrt()})` (it could be fixed by complicating the macro, too).

Comment: I haven't given the The Little Book of Rust Macros a read just yet, but maybe this would be a nice addition to it.

Comment: I have several crazy macros like this. I'm considering starting my own macro blog series.

Answer (score 5):

There are serious limitations to what you can do with macros. E.g. you cannot have parsing ambiguities. So you can't have an expression that expects a `+` after it. This means we need to separate our parsing tokens by e.g. a comma. Then we need to specify the basic binary operations. And finally a mapping from infix to infix with brackets or to prefix. An example using the infix to infix with brackets method is:

```
macro_rules! compute {
    ($a:expr, +, $b:expr) => {{ add($a, $b) }};
    ($a:expr, *, $b:expr) => {{ mul($a, $b) }};
    ($a:expr, +, $($rest:tt)*) => {{
        compute!($a, +, compute!($($rest)*))
    }};
    ($a:expr, *, $b:expr, $($rest:tt)*) => {{
        compute!(compute!($a, *, $b), $($rest)*)
    }};
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=dc873bd18076cf29f629c82d911136b1&version=stable&backtrace=0)

You can now call this macro almost like in your question: `compute!(1, +, 2, *, 3)`

Comment: So the basic limitation would be the fact that you're not allowed to have `+` after `expr` because it would be ambiguous, right? Which means that ambiguity also applies to patterns, not only Rust rules.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Rust rules". But obviously if you have an expression that is followed by a `+`, then you need another expression after that. Rust can't possibly know that you meant to parse an expression until the first `+`, and that would be very weird in general. There might be a way to use `tt` instead of `expr`, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on ideas from [The Little Book of Rust Macros](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/introduction.html) (TT-Munching or Internal Rules). One can parse an expression tree by calling the macro recursively on subtrees. This results in slightly simpler code than scanning linearly through the expression.

```
// Macro DSL for exprs
macro_rules! expr {
    (@expt $fun:ident($($t:tt)*)) => {Expr::$fun(Box::new(expr!($($t)*)))};
    (@expt $col:ident) => {Expr::Var(stringify!($col).to_string())};
    (@expt $val:literal) => {Expr::Lit($val)};
    (@expt ($($t:tt)*)) => {(expr!($($t)*))};
    // Look for /
    (@exp/ [$($x:tt)*]) => {expr!(@expt $($x)*)}; // We are done, look for lower priority ops
    (@exp/ [$($x:tt)*] / $($t:tt)*) => {Expr::Div(Box::new(expr!(@expt $($x)*)), Box::new(expr!(@exp/ $($t)*)))}; // Consume until the op
    (@exp/ [$($x:tt)*] $h:tt $($t:tt)*) => {expr!(@exp/ [$($x)* $h] $($t)*)}; // Consume the tokens until we find the right op
    (@exp/ $($t:tt)*) => {expr!(@exp/ [] $($t)*)}; // Start consuming tokens
    // Look for *
    (@exp* [$($x:tt)*]) => {expr!(@exp/ $($x)*)}; // We are done, look for lower priority ops
    (@exp* [$($x:tt)*] * $($t:tt)*) => {Expr::Mul(Box::new(expr!(@exp/ $($x)*)), Box::new(expr!(@exp* $($t)*)))}; // Consume until the op
    (@exp* [$($x:tt)*] $h:tt $($t:tt)*) => {expr!(@exp* [$($x)* $h] $($t)*)}; // Consume the tokens until we find the right op
    (@exp* $($t:tt)*) => {expr!(@exp* [] $($t)*)}; // Start consuming tokens
    // Look for -
    (@exp- [$($x:tt)*]) => {expr!(@exp* $($x)*)}; // We are done, look for lower priority ops
    (@exp- [$($x:tt)*] - $($t:tt)*) => {Expr::Sub(Box::new(expr!(@exp* $($x)*)), Box::new(expr!(@exp- $($t)*)))}; // Consume until the op
    (@exp- [$($x:tt)*] $h:tt $($t:tt)*) => {expr!(@exp- [$($x)* $h] $($t)*)}; // Consume the tokens until we find the right op
    (@exp- $($t:tt)*) => {expr!(@exp- [] $($t)*)}; // Start consuming tokens
    // Look for +
    (@exp+ [$($x:tt)*]) => {expr!(@exp- $($x)*)}; // We are done, look for lower priority ops
    (@exp+ [$($x:tt)*] + $($t:tt)*) => {Expr::Add(Box::new(expr!(@exp- $($x)*)), Box::new(expr!(@exp+ $($t)*)))}; // Consume until the op
    (@exp+ [$($x:tt)*] $h:tt $($t:tt)*) => {expr!(@exp+ [$($x)* $h] $($t)*)}; // Consume the tokens until we find the right op
    (@exp+ $($t:tt)*) => {expr!(@exp+ [] $($t)*)}; // Start consuming tokens
    // Look for high priority ops first
    ($($t:tt)*) => {expr!(@exp+ $($t)*)};
}
```

The macro:

```
expr!(Exp(a*b + Cos(2.*z)*d - 2.*(y+3.) + t*Sin(c+3.*t)));
```

expands to:

```
Expr::Exp(Box::new(Expr::Add(
    Box::new(Expr::Mul(
        Box::new(Expr::Var("a".to_string())),
        Box::new(Expr::Var("b".to_string())),
    )),
    Box::new(Expr::Add(
        Box::new(Expr::Sub(
            Box::new(Expr::Mul(
                Box::new(Expr::Cos(Box::new(Expr::Mul(
                    Box::new(expr!(@exp/2.)),
                    Box::new(expr!(@exp*z)),
                )))),
                Box::new(Expr::Var("d".to_string())),
            )),
            Box::new(Expr::Mul(
                Box::new(Expr::Lit(2.)),
                Box::new((Expr::Add(Box::new(expr!(@exp*[]y)), Box::new(expr!(@exp-[]3.))))),
            )),
        )),
        Box::new(Expr::Mul(
            Box::new(Expr::Var("t".to_string())),
            Box::new(Expr::Sin(Box::new(Expr::Add(
                Box::new(expr!(@exp-[]c)),
                Box::new(expr!(@exp+[]3.*t)),
            )))),
        )),
    )),
)));
```

The code is [there](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=90d5bd39a561adcd2e0a609757daca6e).